# How to optimally apply a function on all items of a dataframe using inputs from another dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am new in python and I am currenlt struggly to do simple things with pandas. I would like to apply the same function to each item of a given dataset but using a time-dependent parameter.

I am working with pandas `DataFrame` with timestamps as index.

Let's say :

> a(i,j) is ith element in column j in a dataframe A (timestamp/index = i and column = j)
>
> b(i) is the ith element in a dataframe B (with a single column)

I want to compute:

> c(i, j) = fct(a(i, j), b(i))

where fct is a function with two arguments z = fct(x, y)

I wrote a code that does it correcly but it is likely not optimal (very slow).
For the example I just used a simple function fct (but in reallity it is more complex)

Inputs:

- df_data: `pandas.DataFrame` with index=timestamps and several columns
- df_parameter: `pandas.DataFrame` with 1 column containing the time-dependent parameter

Here is the code:

```
# p.concat is required as timestamps are not identical in df_data & df_parameters
import numpy as np
import pandas as p

temp = p.concat([df_data, df_parameter], join='inner', axis=1)
index = temp.index
np_data = temp[nacelleWindSpeeds.columns].values
np_parameter = temp[airDensity.columns].values

import math 

def fct(x, y):
    return math.pow(x, y)

def test(np_data, np_parameter):
    np_result = np.empty(np_data.shape, dtype=float)
    it = np.nditer(np_data, flags=['multi_index'])

    while not it.finished:
        np_result[it.multi_index] = fct(it[0].item(),
                                        np_parameter[it.multi_index[0]][0])
        it.iternext()

    df_final=p.DataFrame(data=np_result, index=index)
    return df_final

final=test(np_data, np_parameter)   

final.to_csv(r'C:\temp\test.csv', sep=';')
```

Here is some example data:

df_data

```
01/03/2010 00:00  ;  9  ;  5  ;  7  
01/03/2010 00:10  ;  9  ;  1  ;  4  
01/03/2010 00:20  ;  5  ;  3  ;  8  
01/03/2010 00:30  ;  7  ;  7  ;  1  
01/03/2010 00:40  ;  8  ;  2  ;  3  
01/03/2010 00:50  ;  0  ;  3  ;  4     
01/03/2010 01:00  ;  4  ;  3  ;  2  
01/03/2010 01:10  ;  6  ;  2  ;  2  
01/03/2010 01:20  ;  6  ;  8  ;  5  
01/03/2010 01:30  ;  7  ;  7  ;  0
```

df_parameter

```
01/03/2010 00:00  ;  2  
01/03/2010 00:10  ;  5  
01/03/2010 00:20  ;  2  
01/03/2010 00:30  ;  3  
01/03/2010 00:40  ;  0  
01/03/2010 00:50  ;  2  
01/03/2010 01:00  ;  4  
01/03/2010 01:10  ;  3  
01/03/2010 01:20  ;  3  
01/03/2010 01:30  ;  1
```

final

```
01/03/2010 00:00  ;  81  ;  25  ;  49  
01/03/2010 00:10  ;  59049  ;  1  ;  1024  
01/03/2010 00:20  ;  25  ;  9  ;  64  
01/03/2010 00:30  ;  343  ;  343  ;  1  
01/03/2010 00:40  ;  1  ;  1  ;  1  
01/03/2010 00:50  ;  0  ;  9  ;  16  
01/03/2010 01:00  ;  256  ;  81  ;  16  
01/03/2010 01:10  ;  216  ;  8  ;  8  
01/03/2010 01:20  ;  216  ;  512  ;  125  
01/03/2010 01:30  ;  7  ;  7  ;  0
```

Thank you very very much in advance for your help,

Patrick

Comment: Please give some example data as from your code it is difficult to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your interest bmu. I've just added the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the optimal way, but this is simpler and should be more efficient as it uses vectorized functions for the calculations:

```
def func(x, y):
    return x ** y

data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep=';', index_col=0, parse_dates=True,
                    header=None, names='abc')
para = pd.read_csv('parameter.dat', sep=';', index_col=0, parse_dates=True,
                    header=None, names=['para'])

for col in data:
    data['%s_result' % col] = func(data[col], para.para)

print data
```

results in

```
                     a  b  c  a_result  b_result  c_result
2010-01-03 00:00:00  9  5  7        81        25        49
2010-01-03 00:10:00  9  1  4     59049         1      1024
2010-01-03 00:20:00  5  3  8        25         9        64
2010-01-03 00:30:00  7  7  1       343       343         1
2010-01-03 00:40:00  8  2  3         1         1         1
2010-01-03 00:50:00  0  3  4         0         9        16
2010-01-03 01:00:00  4  3  2       256        81        16
2010-01-03 01:10:00  6  2  2       216         8         8
2010-01-03 01:20:00  6  8  5       216       512       125
2010-01-03 01:30:00  7  7  0         7         7         0
```

If your real function is more complex you should even try to vectorize it or use [numpy.vectorize()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) as the next best solution.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply and this pretty formulation. Unfortunately this works fine only if you are able to use a vectorized function. In my case, my function uses a dictionnary and this cann be vectorized this I think. I am wrong ?

Comment: @user1415325 In most  cases you can vectorize your function and you should do it to be efficient. did you had a look at `numpy.vectorize()` as the next best solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is indeed what I was missing. The "magic" numpy.vectorize() function !!!! Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @user1415325 I updated the answer. If this answers your question please consider to mark the answer as solved.

Comment: What is strange is that it is faster to first extract the data from the DataFrame (as numpy array), then run the function and finally  reconstruct a DataFrame...

Comment: @user1415325 Maybe it would be a better solution to post another question with your real function. So one can have a look on it and find out how it can be made faster and why it is faster with a numpy array (This sounds interesting). Otherwise you can update your question with your real function.

Comment: Indeed. I will look again and post a new question if required :-) Thanks again for this answer to my first post. I'll create an account right now :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the `map` function, or `numpy.vectorize`; it's also possible to do it with lambda functions. For example:

```
import numpy as np
def fct(x, y):
    return x**y

A = np.array([[9, 5, 7],
       [9, 1, 4],
       [5, 3, 8],
       [7, 7, 1],
       [8, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 4],
       [4, 3, 2],
       [6, 2, 2],
       [6, 8, 5],
       [7, 7, 0]])
B = np.array([2, 5, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1])
C1 = np.asarray(map(fct, A, B))
C2 = np.asarray(map(lambda x,y: x**y, A, B))

vfunc = np.vectorize(fct)
C3 = vfunc(A, np.row_stack(B))
```

Or via Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pdA = pd.DataFrame(A)
pdB = pd.DataFrame(B)
C4 = np.asarray(map(lambda x,y: x**y, pdA.values, pdB.values))
pdC = pd.DataFrame(C4)
```

Note that C1, C2, C3 and C4 are all equal:

```
>>> print np.array_equal(C1,C2), np.array_equal(C2,C3), np.array_equal(C3,C4)
True True True
```